# Using an Input to Retrieve a Corresponding Element From a 2D Array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

This might be a really obvious solution to some, but, being pretty new to python, I'm unsure how to do it - In short, I want to take a user's input, and find the corresponding element on a 2D array, i.e. an input of '1' would print 'a', '2' would print 'b', and so on. Is there a way to do this?
The code I've written so far is below

```
var=[["1","a"],["2","b"],["3","c"]]
inp='x'
while inp!='1' and inp!='2' and inp!='3':
  inp=str(input("Enter a number 1-3\n"))
```

I've not got a clue what to try, and I'm yet to find a solution - that just might be due to my poor phrasing though - so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways of doing what you want to do.  Here's a way that is easier for a beginner to understand (hopefully):

```
var=[["1","a"],["2","b"],["3","c"]]
inp='x'
while inp!='1' and inp!='2' and inp!='3':
  inp=input("Enter a number 1-3\n")

for entry in var:
    if entry[0] == inp:
        print(entry[1])
        break
```

Note that I removed the call to `str()` that you had put around your call to `input()`, as that function already returns a string value.

A better way to do this if you can choose the form of your input data structure is to use a map rather than a list.  Here's how to do that.  Note how much simpler the added code becomes:

```
var= {'1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c'}
inp='x'
while inp!='1' and inp!='2' and inp!='3':
  inp=input("Enter a number 1-3\n")

print(var[inp])
```

...and to make it so you don't have to hard-code valid inputs:

```
var= {'1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c'}
inp='x'
while inp not in var:
  inp=input("Enter a number 1-3\n")

print(var[inp])
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the sub-lists inside `var` until you find one where the first element matches the user input.  Then print the second element of that sub-list.

```
for sublist in var:
    if sublist[0] == inp:
        print(sublist[1])
```